# No such field error given by selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, grid, remotewebdriver

I am trying to execute tests on selenium grid.I am getting no such field error when the RemoteDriver.driver.navigate().to(Link); is executed

Comment: I have configured the grid and run tests on one node.When i run the jUnit tests and then see the jUNIT log i can see the error -<testcase time="0.011" name="Test_1" classname="Visibility_ValidateIcons">

<error type="java.lang.NoSuchFieldError" message="driver">java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: driver at Utils.GoToLink(Utils.java:185) at ValidateIcons.Test_1(ValidateIcons.java:21) </error>

</testcase>

Comment: the browser sessions starts but the page I am trying to navigate to doesnt open up on the node